# Control iTunes with Keyboard Shortcuts on Windows

Tags: windows, itunes, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to configure either iTunes or my keyboard to communicate clearly with eachother when I press my pause/play button on my keyboard? My keyboard does control Windows Media Player, but not iTunes. Is this an interface issue that can be remedied?

I'm using the Dynex (DX-WKBD) keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Hill apparently wrote [a couple of small programs to deal with this problem](http://andy.hillhome.org/code/ituneskeys).

Comment: OMG! that iTunesKeys 12MB in RAM, in Vista x64? And writing in any application is so slow. C'mon...

Comment: I did not find anything else that seems confirmed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I keep seeing mention of mmkeys.dll (see http://www.everythingitunes.com/os/windows/2008-01-04/mmkeysdll/) but I haven't been able to find any info on the author so I don't know how to confirm if it also does anything nefarious (like key logging).